# Three php scripts in one, is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hey is it possible to make three scripts into one with the following code?

Can I just move "result" to the first script?

Here are codes:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_NOTICE);
$nazwabazydanych = "projekt";

$pesel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pesel']);
$imie = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['imie']);  
$nazwisko = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nazwisko']);
$telefon = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telefon']);
$adres = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adres']);
$nr_konta = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nr_konta']);
$zarobek = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zarobek']);

if (!$pesel || !$imie || !$nazwisko || !$telefon || !$adres || !$nr_konta || !$zarobek)

 {
        print "Nie zostały wypełnione wszystkie pola";
        exit;
 }

 if (strlen($pesel) != 11 )
 {
 print "Zły numer pesel! Pesel powinien mieć 11 cyfr.";
 }

 if (strlen($telefon) != 9 )
 {
 print "Zły numer telefonu! Telefon powinien mieć 9 cyfr.";
 }

 if (strlen($nr_konta) != 20 )
 {
 print "Zły numer konta! Numer konta powinien mieć 20 cyfr.";
 }

$db = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$db)  
        {  
        print "Nie można nawiązać połączenia z bazą danych";
        exit;
        }

mysql_select_db("$nazwabazydanych");

$result = mysql_query("CALL dodaj_osobe ('$pesel','$imie','$nazwisko','$telefon','$adres','$nr_konta','$zarobek')"); 
if (!$result) {
    print('');
}
else
{
    print('Dodano nowa osobe');
}



?>
```

Second code and "thrid", the third is the same with only 1 change:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_NOTICE);
$nazwabazydanych = "projekt";

$pesel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pesel']);



if (!$pesel)

 {
        print "Nie zostały wypełnione wszystkie pola";
        exit;
 }

   if (strlen($pesel) != 11 )
 {
 print "Zły numer pesel! Pesel powinien mieć 11 cyfr.";
 }

$db = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$db)  
        {  
        print "Nie można nawiązać połączenia z bazą danych";
        exit;
        }

mysql_select_db("$nazwabazydanych");

$result = mysql_query("CALL magic_button ('$pesel',1)"); 
if (!$result) {
    print('');
}
else
{
    print('IT WORKS!');
}

?>
```

The change in third is :

```
$result = mysql_query("CALL magic_button1 ('$pesel',-11)");
```

Any suggestion, how can I make them into one?

Comment: have you heard about include() and require()? Look it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call include one PHP file within another using [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php).

As an example:

```
// foo.php
echo "hello";

// bar.php
echo "world!";

// helloworld.php
require('foo.php');
require('bar.php');
```

Output

```
helloworld!
```

---

Aside from that, you'll have to clean up that big, messy code dump